# Why is my Ares not Working?

Tags: internet, firewall, file-sharing, isp

I recently increased my blink broadband speed and now my Ares is not connecting. I spoke to the blink peeps and they deactivated my firewall..but Ares still is not working. What do i do?

Comment: Consider rephrasing and retagging your question, please. And from what I can understand, you might wanna call the hotline of your ISP with this, sounds like an issue they could easily fix.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar issues with Ares.
Ares has a really hard time bootstrapping; there are some sites you can look for to get superpeer lists (I don't remember them offhand but a quick Google for Ares forums will get you there). Ares has some very specific requirements for it's superpeers right down to what port that have to run on so it might just take time.